# valgrind errors regarding malloc: what do they mean?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I get this Error and I am not sure what it means.

```
Evaluating a Virtualized Heap of 1 KBs...
numIterations: 1000

==17272== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17272==    at 0x4C2FABC: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17272==    by 0x108DCF: VMalloc (aMalloc_part2.c:157)
==17272==    by 0x108EE5: VPut (aMalloc_part2.c:182)
==17272==    by 0x109095: vMem_part2 (aMalloc_part2.c:240)
==17272==    by 0x10935B: main (aMalloc_part2.c:283)
==17272==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17272==    at 0x108FD2: vMem_part2 (aMalloc_part2.c:226)
```

#### This is my Relevant code:

```
enter code here
    // VMalloc
addrs_t* VMalloc (size_t size) {
    //get initial value before allignment
    addrs_t* addr;
    int initial_size = size;
    size = (size+(0x8-size%0x8)%0x8);
    int i=0;
    //printf("In vmalloc\n");
    addr = (addrs_t*)malloc(sizeof(addrs_t)*(size/8));
    if (addr==NULL) { printf("Null malloc addr: VMalloc\n"); }
    i=0;
    while(i<size/8) {
        addr[i]=(addrs_t)malloc(sizeof(addr[i])*8);
        if (addr[i]==NULL) {
            printf("VMalloc Couldnt allocate mem\n");
        }
        i=i+1;
    }
    return addr;
}
```

`addr_t *addr` is a pointer to pointer. (`typedef addr_t char*`)

**This is the part that calls VMalloc.**

```
for (i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
        addr1 = PUT(s, n+1);
```

#### Function PUT looks like this:

There is aliasing using def so it may call PUT<->VPut. They are same.

```
addrs_t* PUT (any_t data, size_t size) {
    addrs_t* rtnVal = VMalloc (size);
    for (int i=0;rtnVal[i]!=NULL;i++) {
        memmove(rtnVal[i],data, 8); // copies byte of data
    }
    return rtnVal;
}
```

Comment: The parameter `size` can be uninitialized. That's very strange allocation. Isn't `sizeof(addr[i])` typo? And those `size+(0x8-size%0x8)%0x8` and `size/8` look really strange.

Comment: Good catch on "size", I fixed that by creating local_size variable. Thanks. size/8 is because I know size comes as multiple of 8. valgrind continues to report sameerrors though.

Comment: So some more info: When I call the function, its being used for a fairly large array. ~/C-Prog/cs250_malloc/ $ ./aMalloc2 1024
Evaluating a Virtualized Heap of 1 KBs...
numIterations: 1000
In vmalloc:: s: 32600 ns: 4075   i.e. size/8 = 4075. Is that a too big heap allocation I am doing? any suggestions??

Comment: OT: regarding: `addr = (addrs_t*)malloc(sizeof(addrs_t)*(size/8));`  in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Also, strongly suggest using `calloc()` so easy to pass each allocation to `free()` before exiting the program.

Comment: regarding: `if (addr==NULL) { printf("Null malloc addr: VMalloc\n"); }`  When the prior call to `malloc()` fails, the code must not try to use the returned value, so before the closing brace '}' should be inserted the statement: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("VMalloc Couldnt allocate mem\n");` and `printf("Null malloc addr: VMalloc\n")`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  And when the error is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  the function: `perror()` is made for this purpose

Comment: The last line of the valgrind report indicates your `vMem_part2` function, which calls `VPut`, seems to be the source of the uninitialized variable.  [Edit] your question to include that function (and `VPut` as well), and indicate which line is line 226.